# Format number number with specific mask regex python

Tags: python, regex, format, string-formatting, mask

I need to format a number with a specifc mask: **9.9.9.9.99.999**, depending on the length of number string.
For example:

```
- 123456789 => 1.2.3.4.56.789
- 123456    => 1.2.3.4.56
- 1234      => 1.2.3.4
- 123       => 1.2.3
- 12        => 1.2
```

It will not occur a number string with 7 or 8 digits in the input.

How could that be implemented with regex, preferably in python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this operation must be repeated a lot of times, there's a 2 times faster solution (mine :)

Comment: I found an even better solution. See my edit 2, please

Comment: @eyquem in my case, performance is not a issue and it had to be done with regular expression. Even though @casimir-et-hippolyte solution is neither the fastest nor the more _readable_, it seems to me to be the _cleaner_ one. Anyway, I saw your new solution (`fmt3` function) and it is really good, really fast.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
(?:(?<=^\d)|(?<=^\d{2})|(?<=^\d{3})|(?<=^\d{4})|(?<=^\d{6}))(?=\d)
```

with `.` as replacement.

example:

```
re.sub(r'(?:(?<=^\d)|(?<=^\d{2})|(?<=^\d{3})|(?<=^\d{4})|(?<=^\d{6}))(?=\d)', '.', yourstr)
```

Comment: I have a regex solution faster than yours and a non-regex solution even faster than the regex one. Will you be interested to see them ?

Answer (score 5):

Does it have to be a regular expression?

```
num = "123456789"

def fmt(num):
    block1 = list(num[:4])
    block2 = len(num) > 4 and [num[4:6]] or []
    block3 = len(num) > 6 and [num[6:]] or []
    return ".".join(block1 + block2 + block3)

print fmt(num)
```

I'm confident I still understand that in two years. Not so sure about the regex.

Comment: Agreed. As fun as regular expressions are, this is much more readable.

Comment: Good one. But I find the ``... and ... or ...`` not so easy to understand. Your answer inspired me for another way, see the edit at the end of my answer

Comment: Your solution inspired me and I finally found a very simple and fast solution. See my edit 2 if you are interested.

Answer (score 4):

Something more general without help of regexp:

```
from itertools import islice
def formatn(n, pat='9.9.9.9.99.999', sep='.'):
    pos = map(len, pat.split(sep))
    it = iter(str(n))
    spl = [''.join(islice(it, p)) for p in pos]
    return sep.join(x for x in spl if x)
```

Demo:

```
>>> formatn(1234)
'1.2.3.4'
>>> formatn(123456789)
'1.2.3.4.56.789'
```

Comment: Huge +1 for solving the general case, including an easy to substitute pattern.

Comment: Generalizing solution, but 10 times slower than other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

A non-regexp way: (this reminds me that I should learn regexp asap)

```
def get_formated_number(num, split_at):
    nums = list(str(num))
    for i in sorted(split_at[len(nums)], reverse=True):
        nums.insert(i, '.')
    return ''.join(nums)

nums = [12, 123, 1234, 123456, 123456789]
split_at = {2: [1], 
            3: [1, 2],
            4: [1, 2, 3],
            6: [1, 2, 3, 4],
            9: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]}

for num in nums:
    print get_formated_number(num, split_at)
```

#### Output

```
1.2
1.2.3
1.2.3.4
1.2.3.4.56
1.2.3.4.56.789
```

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT 2

I found a solution 2 times faster than my regex solution that was the fastest one.
And it doesn't need a regex:

```
def fmt3(num):
   return '.'.join((num[0:1],num[1:2],num[2:3],num[3:4],
                     num[4:6],num[6:])).rstrip('.')
```

I think it's because access to elements of a string is extremely fast.

.

It can be generalized, as did **alko**, but it keeps an acceptable execution's time, similar to other solutions, while **alko**'s solution is 10 times slower than all the other solutions.

```
def fmt4(num,mask = '9.9.9.9.99.999'):
    def gen(mask,a = 0,b = 0,li = []):
        for c in mask:
            if c=='.':
                yield num[a:b]
                a = b
            else:
                b += 1
        yield num[a:b]
    return '.'.join(gen(mask)).strip('.')

print fmt4('123456789')
print fmt4('123456')
print fmt4('1234')
print fmt4('123')
print fmt4('12')
print
print fmt4('123456789',mask = '.9.99.9.99.99.9')
print fmt4('123456789',mask = '9.99.9.99.99.9')
print fmt4('123456789',mask = '9...99.9.99.99.9')
print fmt4('123456789',mask = '9.99.9.99.99.9.')
print fmt4('123456789',mask = '9.99.99999.9')
```

result

```
1.2.3.4.56.789
1.2.3.4.56
1.2.3.4
1.2.3
1.2

1.23.4.56.78.9
1.23.4.56.78.9
1...23.4.56.78.9
1.23.4.56.78.9
1.23.45678.9
```

#### MY INITIAL ANSWER

My following solution ,
with `pat1 = '(\d)(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d\d)?(\d\d\d)?'`
and `'.'.join(filter(None,r1.match(thestring).groups('')))`
seems to be the  fastest;

```
import re
from time import clock

from itertools import islice
def formatn(n, pat='9.9.9.9.99.999', sep='.'):
    pos = map(len, pat.split(sep))
    it = iter(str(n))
    spl = [''.join(islice(it, p)) for p in pos]
    return sep.join(x for x in spl if x)

def fmt(num):
    block1 = list(num[:4])
    block2 = len(num) > 4 and [num[4:6]] or []
    block3 = len(num) > 6 and [num[6:]] or []
    return ".".join(block1 + block2 + block3)

pat1 = '(\d)(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d\d)?(\d\d\d)?'
r1 = re.compile(pat1)

pat2 = '(?:(?<=^\d)|(?<=^\d{2})|(?<=^\d{3})|(?<=^\d{4})|(?<=^\d{6}))(?=\d)'
r2 = re.compile(pat2)

iterat = 20000

te = clock()
for i in xrange(iterat):
    '.'.join(filter(None,r1.match('123456789').groups('')))
print clock()-te
print '  ','.'.join(filter(None,r1.match('123456789').groups('')))

te = clock()
for i in xrange(iterat):
    r2.sub('.','123456789')
print clock()-te
print '  ',r2.sub('.','123456789')

te = clock()
for i in xrange(iterat):
    fmt('123456789')
print clock()-te
print '  ',fmt('123456789')

te = clock()
for i in xrange(iterat):
    formatn('123456789')
print clock()-te
print '  ',formatn('123456789')

print '-----------------------------'

te = clock()
for i in xrange(iterat):
    '.'.join(filter(None,r1.match('123456').groups()))
print clock()-te
print '  ','.'.join(filter(None,r1.match('123456').groups()))

te = clock()
for i in xrange(iterat):
    r2.sub('.','123456')
print clock()-te
print "  ",r2.sub('.','123456')

te = clock()
for i in xrange(iterat):
    fmt('123456')
print clock()-te
print '  ',fmt('123456')

te = clock()
for i in xrange(iterat):
    formatn('123456789')
print clock()-te
print '  ',formatn('123456789')

print '-----------------------------'

te = clock()
for i in xrange(iterat):
    '.'.join(filter(None,r1.match('1234').groups()))
print clock()-te
print '  ','.'.join(filter(None,r1.match('1234').groups()))

te = clock()
for i in xrange(iterat):
    r2.sub('.','1234')
print clock()-te
print '  ',r2.sub('.','1234')

te = clock()
for i in xrange(iterat):
    fmt('1234')
print clock()-te
print '  ',fmt('1234')

te = clock()
for i in xrange(iterat):
    formatn('1234')
print clock()-te
print '  ',formatn('1234')
```

result

```
0.186308036357
   1.2.3.4.56.789
0.397971250536
   1.2.3.4.56.789
0.258452959804
   1.2.3.4.56.789
1.9979410791
   1.2.3.4.56.789
-----------------------------
0.208518959812
   1.2.3.4.56
0.319339748488
   1.2.3.4.56
0.247042291688
   1.2.3.4.56
1.97725548918
   1.2.3.4.56.789
-----------------------------
0.179872581571
   1.2.3.4
0.273376644238
   1.2.3.4
0.207427200943
   1.2.3.4
1.9792909434
   1.2.3.4
```

### EDIT

Inspired by Lukas Graf's answer:

```
def fmt2(num):
    a = '.'.join(num[:4])
    b = num[4:6]
    c = num[6:]
    return '%s.%s.%s' % (a,b,c) if c \
           else a + '.' + b if b else a
```

Comment: This `fmt2` solution is even faster than your regex approach. Good one.

Comment: Ah ? My tests (not edited to display them) show that it is the second longest solution after ``formatn()``