# How can I mask my float number, preferably without using regex?

Tags: python, regex, format, string-formatting, mask

How can I format a float number to string, by using a mask?

(I'm not proficient in regex, but if someone knows an one-line solution, why not?)

**Here is my problem:**

I have a float number like "6.88" and I need to format it using the following mask "00000000000.00"

> 6.88 = "00000000006.88"
>
> 14.3 = "00000000014.30"
>
> 00.0 = "00000000000.00"

I've already read the following post but I couldn't understood it:

[Format number number with specific mask regex python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031668/format-number-number-with-specific-mask-regex-python)

**Example of my data:**

```
6.88  => 00000000006.88
56.62 => 00000000056.62
9.58  => 00000000009.58
24.75 => 00000000024.75
14.30 => 00000000014.30
```

**My not so efficient nor fast solution:**

1. convert from float to str
2. split my string using the separator "."
3. count chars before and after "."
4. adapt my split[0] and split[1] to the mask, by using the length of these parameters
5. done

---

**Is there an easier way to do this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
In [21]: '{:014.2f}'.format(6.88)
Out[21]: '00000000006.88'

In [22]: '{:014.2f}'.format(14.30)
Out[22]: '00000000014.30'

In [23]: '{:014.2f}'.format(0)
Out[23]: '00000000000.00'
```

According to [*6.1.3.1. Format Specification Mini-Language*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language),

- `0` is the fill character
- `.2` sets the precision to 2
- 14 is the width of the result string

Comment: Wow! It works perfectly! Thanks a lot for teaching me that! - "Easy as Py"

Answer (score -1):

Another example based on string formatting (not very nice or error prone):

```
def format_float(string_format, number):
    _int, _frac = string_format.split(".")
    real_format = "%%%s%d.%df" % ("0", len(_int) + len(_frac) + 1, len(_frac))
    return real_format % number

print format_float("00000.000", 1.2)
```

would yield: *00001.200*

Comment: If your going to use old style formatting do `'%014.2f' % the_number`.   This is buggy overkill.

Comment: It's what the function does, converts the "00000000000.00" (those are given) format into "%014.2f" (accepted by string formatting routines). I didn't simply hardcoded it, to keep it more general, If the format changes ("0" s added or removed), the code doesn't need to change.